# Drawing a stretchable Line in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to draw a line which stretch when its parent container stretch itself and it collapse when its parents collapse itself.

I develop a user control for this purpose and this control is placed in scroll viewer for some reasons.

I have binded the X2 Property of the line with the width of parent control. It solves the problem while stretching the parent control  but while collapsing it is not letting the control decrease its size and scrollviewer adds a scrollbar for it.

```
 Binding binding = new Binding("ActualWidth")
        {
            ElementName = Grid1.Name
        };
        Line mainLine = new Line
        {
            X1 = 0,
            HorizontalAlignment=System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
            StrokeThickness = 2,              
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
        };

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(mainLine, Line.X2Property, binding);
        Grid1.Children.Add(mainLine);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(mainLine, 4);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a `Rectangle` to do that:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
               Fill="Black" 
               Height="2"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks that works. Upvote. I still want to wait for sometime to see if this is somehow possible with the line as well. And it'll be great if you could tell me why it is not working with line.

Comment: @MegaMind While `Line` and `Rectangle` are both `Shape`s, only `Rectangle` uses Measure and Arrange to change its layout.

Comment: Although https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393%28v=vs.110%29.aspx claims that line is a stretchable shape it doesn't seem like it actually does.